# wordpress use shortcode when post open

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am new in wordpress.

So, i create shortcode to get value and display it in post.

In post like:

```
<img src="http://.../test.jpg" />
example
[my_shortcode]
```

Everything is ok, post loaded value, in homepage can see it.

But, i just want use shortcode when post open.

That mean, in homepage can see, post just show image and text like:

```
<img src="http://.../test.jpg" />
example
```

After post open, image and text and value is show. With value get by shortcode.

How to do it with wordpress?

Comment: What do you mean by _"use shortcode when post already displayed"_? If the post is displayed, it's already been rendered. How would you "use" a short code then? And to do what?

Comment: You can see my question again. I mean in homepage can see, post don't use shortcode. After open it, post use shortcode.

Comment: You need to be way more clear about what you're asking. _"After open it, use shortcode"_ doesn't clarify anything. It doesn't answer any of my questions in my first comment either. Please update your question with a _clear_ explanation of what it is you're trying to do and what the result should be.

Comment: I know, but difficult to explain it. That mean, in homepage can see, post just show image and text. After open it, post show image, text and value. With value get by shortcode.

Comment: I was update my question.

Comment: You use conditional is_home in your file php, example `if(!is_home()) { echo do_shortcode('[my_shortcode]'); }` if not home show shortcode

Comment: @GuillermoAndresFuentesMoral: Can you explain it? Bacuase i'm new in wordpress.